# Loop through cells in Google Sheet and remove a subString of text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I need to loop through each populated cell in my Google Sheet and remove these characters:  `{stringValue=}`.

One of my columns looks like this:

```
COLUMN NAME: category
{stringValue=Pump}
{stringValue=Motor}
{stringValue=Motor}
{stringValue=Flow Meter}
{stringValue=Flow Meter}
{stringValue=Flow Meter}
{stringValue=Motor}
{stringValue=Flow Meter}
{stringValue=Pump}
{stringValue=Motor}
{stringValue=Pump}
```

I need to keep text such as Motor or Pump.

This is how I populate the sheet:

```
function importData() {
  const firestore = getFirestore();

  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments('Data').map(function(document) {
    return document.fields;
  });

  const first = allDocuments[0];
  const columns = Object.keys(first);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  ss.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(columns);

  allDocuments.forEach(function(document) {
    const row = columns.map(function(column) {
      return document[column];
    });
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation using Google Apps Script.. These values are put in a column.

  - From

    ```
      COLUMN NAME: category
      {stringValue=Pump}
      {stringValue=Motor}
      {stringValue=Motor}
      {stringValue=Flow Meter}
      {stringValue=Flow Meter}
      {stringValue=Flow Meter}
      {stringValue=Motor}
      {stringValue=Flow Meter}
      {stringValue=Pump}
      {stringValue=Motor}
      {stringValue=Pump}
    ```
  - To

    ```
      COLUMN NAME: category
      Pump
      Motor
      Motor
      Flow Meter
      Flow Meter
      Flow Meter
      Motor
      Flow Meter
      Pump
      Motor
      Pump
    ```

In this case, I would like to propose to use TextFinder. I thought that when the TextFinder is used, your goal can be achieve your goal with the low process cost. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const columnNumber = 1; // Please set the column number. 1 is the column "A".

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet
    .getRange(2, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
    .createTextFinder("\\{stringValue\\=(.+)\\}")
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith("$1");
}
```

- If you want to replace for the various `stringValue`, I think that you can also use `\\{.+\\=(.+)\\}` instead of `\\{stringValue\\=(.+)\\}`.
- About your new question of `How would you clear any cells that only contain {stringValue=} when there is no data in that field?`, in this case, how about modifying the regex in `createTextFinder` from `\\{stringValue\\=(.+)\\}` to `\\{stringValue\\=(.+|)\\}`? By this, the value of `{stringValue=}` is replaced with the empty.

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following situation is obtained.

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thanks for this.  How would you clear any cells that only contain  ```{stringValue=}``` when there is no data in that field?

Comment: @Ciaran Crowley Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to propose to modify the regex in `createTextFinder` from `\\{stringValue\\=(.+)\\}` to `\\{stringValue\\=(.+|)\\}`? By this, the value of `{stringValue=}` is replaced with the empty. For this, also I updated my answer. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you once again.  As before, your solution works perfectly.  There is no need for any apologies.  The column I i gave in my original question just happened to not have any fields just containing ```{stringValue=}```.

Comment: @Ciaran Crowley Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a script but also can be done with a formula as follows:

```
=LEFT(MID(A18,FIND("=",A18)+1,100),LEN(MID(A18,FIND("=",A18)+1,100))-1)
```

Now it seems the "=" is always at position 13, if so, the FIND() function can be removed and you can hard code 13 to simplify the function.

[image]

You can copy this formula down as needed or use an array formula instead and it will populate itself as needed:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A18:A <> "",LEFT(MID(A18:A,FIND("=",A18:A)+1,100),LEN(MID(A18:A,FIND("=",A18:A)+1,100))-1),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with Find/Replace:

1.) Select the entire target column.

2.) Hit Ctrl-H to open the Find/Replace dialog.

3.) In the "Find" field enter the following: `^.+=(.+).`

4.) In the "Replace with" field enter the following: `$1`

5.) Check the box that says "Search using regular expressions."

6.) Click the button that says "Replace All."

The whole process takes about 10 seconds.